# Add a column containing the id of the previous row in each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to add a column that contains the id of the previous row in each group.

Sample:

```
Product       ID
Orange        1
Orange        2
Orange        3
Orange        4
Apple         5
Apple         6
Apple         7
Grapes        8
Grapes        9
```

Desired output:

```
Product       ID
Orange        1
Orange        1
Orange        2
Orange        3
Apple         5
Apple         5
Apple         6
Grapes        8
Grapes        8
```

Thank you!

Comment: I want too. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I used MIN([Id) OVER (PARTITION BY Description) but this is only getting the first row in each group.

Comment: As LAG is not available in the versions mentioned, you will have to find a workaround. Hint: The previous ID is the highest ID of all smaller IDs. If the IDs don't have gaps, then you can even subtract one from each ID, except for the smallest IDs per product.

Comment: @ohhzumm check my answer, maybe that is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If correctly understood your question You can try something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product, 
                MIN(Id) OVER (PARTITION BY Product) Id
FROM #Products

UNION ALL

SELECT Product, Id
FROM (
    SELECT Product, 
           Id, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY ID DESC) AS rn
FROM #Products
)x
WHERE rn <> 1
ORDER BY Id
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Product Id
Orange  1
Orange  1
Orange  2
Orange  3
Apple   5
Apple   5
Apple   6
Grapes  8
Grapes  8
```

Comment: it is giving duplication and count is increased

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this using `outer apply` or a correlated subquery.  Normally, with no previous id, `NULL` would be perfectly acceptable:

```
select s.*, s2.id as previd
from sample s outer apply
     (select top 1 s2.id
      from sample s2
      where s2.product = s.product and s2.id < s.id
      order by s2.id desc
     ) s2 ;
```

You seem to want the first `id` in this case.  Here is a one fix:

```
select s.*, coalesce(s2.id, smin.minid) as previd
from sample s outer apply
     (select top 1 s2.id
      from sample s2
      where s2.product = s.product and s2.id < s.id
      order by s2.id desc
     ) s2 outer apply
     (select min(s2.id) as minid
      from sample s2
      where s2.product = s.product
     ) mins;
```

Of course, in SQL Server 2012+, you would use the ANSI standard function `lag()`:

```
select s.*,
       coalesce(lag(s.id) over (partition by s.product order by s.id),
                min(s.id) over (partition by s.product)
               ) as sprev
from sample s;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DUMMY TABLE
  (
    Product VARCHAR(6) ,
    ID INT
  );

INSERT  INTO @DUMMY ( Product, ID )
VALUES  ( 'Orange', 1 ),
        ( 'Orange', 2 ),
        ( 'Orange', 3 ),
        ( 'Orange', 4 ),
        ( 'Apple', 5 ),
        ( 'Apple', 6 ),
        ( 'Apple', 7 ),
        ( 'Grapes', 8 ),
        ( 'Grapes', 9 );


WITH  dummy
        AS (
             SELECT [Product], [ID],
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY ID ) AS rn
             FROM   @DUMMY AS [d]
           )
  SELECT  [d1].[Product], [d1].[ID], [d2].[ID]
  FROM    dummy AS [d1]
  LEFT JOIN dummy AS [d2] ON [d2].[Product] = [d1].[Product] AND
                             [d2].[rn] + 1 = [d1].[rn]
  ORDER BY d1.[ID];
```

PS: If it were 2012 or later then it supports ROWS/RANGE as PostgreSQL does.
PS2: You can use SQLFiddle to give the sample data as code instead of plain text.